# How TensorFlow splice tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tf segment.
Input is two list (convert to tensor)

```
def run():
    res = {}
    data = [11,22,33,44,55]
    segment_ids = [6,6,7,7,8]
    data = tf.convert_to_tensor(data)
    segment_ids = tf.convert_to_tensor(segment_ids)
    # some operation
    # ...
    return res
```

for output, I want get the follows:

```
res[0] = tensor (value: [11,22])
res[1] = tensor (value: [33,44])
res[2] = tensor (value: [55])
```

the key of res is the index of different segment ids ( list(6,7,8) index: [0,1,2] ).
the value is the corresponding data of each segment ids.

corresponds to index zero then in that case, res[0] is [11,11]

Comment: `6,6` corresponds to `index zero` then in that case, `res[0]` should give `[11,11]`, right? You can add more information to clarify the problem statement.

Comment: yes, res[0] is [11,11]